# Powershell format operator inside function

Tags: string, powershell

I've found out the format operator is working differently inside a function compared to a plain script.
Here's a simple example of what is working as expected:

```
[string]$name = 'Scripting Guy'
[string]$statement = 'PowerShell rocks'
$s = "The {0} thinks that {1}!" -f $name, $statement
write-host $s
```

producing:

```
The Scripting Guy thinks that PowerShell rocks!
```

While inside a function it does something different:

```
function myFunc( [string] $iname, [string] $istatement) { 
    $s = "The {0} thinks that {1}!" -f $iname, $istatement
    write-host $s
}

[string]$name = 'Scripting Guy'
[string]$statement = 'PowerShell rocks'
myFunc($name, $statement)
```

produces:

```
The Scripting Guy PowerShell rocks thinks that !
```

I tried to play with it to find out what it's doing:

```
function myFunc( [string] $iname, [string] $istatement) { 
    $s = "The {0} thinks that {1}! {2} {3}" -f $iname, $istatement, "=====", $iname
    write-host $s
}

[string]$name = 'Scripting Guy'
[string]$statement = 'PowerShell rocks'
myFunc($name, $statement)
```

This produces:

```
The Scripting Guy PowerShell rocks thinks that ! ===== Scripting Guy PowerShell rocks
```

So now I don't know what to think about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the function as follows:

```
myFunc -iname "Scripting Guy" -istatement "Powershell Rocks!!"
```

or

```
myFunc $name $statement
```

The current method you're using passes a single array object that's why the elements get printed in succession